# Exit polling with timeout

Tags: typescript, polling

I am looking for an elegant way to break out of this poll:

```
private pollLinkResult() {
        (function poll() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                   //call the service layer to do an ajax call
                //depending on the result I would like to exit the infinite poll
            }, 1000);
        })();      
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the condition that you're supposed to stop polling on?

Comment: for example jsonContentFromAjax.Completed === true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private pollLinkResult() {
        (function poll() {
            let myTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                   //call the service layer to do an ajax call
                //depending on the result I would like to exit the infinite poll
if(yourCondition){
clearTimeout(myTimeout);
}
            }, 1000);
        })();      
}
```